# Error 1503: The service did not respond to the start or control request in timely fashion

Tags: c++, service, atl

I've recently added a Windows Service. When I run **Administrative Tools > Services** and then start `ProjectName service`, I get the following error :

> Windows could not start the ProjectName service on LocalComputer.
>
> Error 1503: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in timely fashion.

Did I misconfigured it?

```
inline HRESULT CServiceModule::RegisterServer(BOOL bRegTypeLib)
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Remove any previous service since it may point to
    // the incorrect file
    Uninstall();
    // Add service entries
    UpdateRegistryFromResource(IDR_ATLBEEPER, TRUE);
    // Create service
    Install();
    // Add object entries
    HRESULT hRes = CComModule::RegisterServer(bRegTypeLib);

    CoUninitialize();
    return hRes;
}

inline HRESULT CServiceModule::UnregisterServer()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    // Remove service entries
    UpdateRegistryFromResource(IDR_ATLBEEPER, FALSE);
    // Remove service
    Uninstall();
    // Remove object entries
    CComModule::UnregisterServer();

    CoUninitialize();
    return S_OK;
}

inline void CServiceModule::Init(_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* p, HINSTANCE h, UINT nServiceNameID)
{
    CComModule::Init(p, h);

    m_bService = TRUE;

    LoadString(h, nServiceNameID, m_szServiceName, sizeof(m_szServiceName) / sizeof(TCHAR));

    // set up the initial service status
    m_hServiceStatus = NULL;
    m_status.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    m_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    m_status.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    m_status.dwWaitHint = 0;
}

LONG CServiceModule::Unlock()
{
    LONG l = CComModule::Unlock();
    if (l == 0 && !m_bService)
        PostThreadMessage(dwThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
    return l;
}

BOOL CServiceModule::IsInstalled()
{
    BOOL bResult = FALSE;

    SC_HANDLE hSCM = ::OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (hSCM != NULL)
    {
        SC_HANDLE hService = ::OpenService(hSCM, m_szServiceName, SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG);
        if (hService != NULL)
        {
            bResult = TRUE;
            ::CloseServiceHandle(hService);
        }
        ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
    }
    return bResult;
}

inline BOOL CServiceModule::Install()
{
    if (IsInstalled())
        return TRUE;

    SC_HANDLE hSCM = ::OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (hSCM == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Couldn't open service manager"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Get the executable file path
    TCHAR szFilePath[_MAX_PATH];
    DWORD dwFLen = ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFilePath, _MAX_PATH);
    if (dwFLen == 0 || dwFLen == MAX_PATH)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("GetModuleFileName failed"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    SC_HANDLE hService = ::CreateService(
        hSCM, m_szServiceName, m_szServiceName,
        SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
        SERVICE_DEMAND_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
        szFilePath, NULL, NULL, _T("RPCSS\0"), NULL, NULL);

    if (hService == NULL)
    {
        ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Couldn't create service"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    ::CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
    return TRUE;
}

inline BOOL CServiceModule::Uninstall()
{
    if (!IsInstalled())
        return TRUE;

    SC_HANDLE hSCM = ::OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

    if (hSCM == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Couldn't open service manager"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }

    SC_HANDLE hService = ::OpenService(hSCM, m_szServiceName, SERVICE_STOP | DELETE);

    if (hService == NULL)
    {
        ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Couldn't open service"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }
    SERVICE_STATUS status;
    ::ControlService(hService, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &status);

    BOOL bDelete = ::DeleteService(hService);
    ::CloseServiceHandle(hService);
    ::CloseServiceHandle(hSCM);

    if (bDelete)
        return TRUE;

    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Service could not be deleted"), m_szServiceName, MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Logging functions
void CServiceModule::LogEvent(LPCTSTR pFormat, ...)
{
    TCHAR    chMsg[256];
    HANDLE  hEventSource;
    LPTSTR  lpszStrings[1];
    va_list pArg;

    va_start(pArg, pFormat);
    _vsntprintf_s(chMsg, sizeof(chMsg), 256, pFormat, pArg);
    chMsg[255] = 0;
    va_end(pArg);

    lpszStrings[0] = chMsg;

    if (m_bService)
    {
        /* Get a handle to use with ReportEvent(). */
        hEventSource = RegisterEventSource(NULL, m_szServiceName);
        if (hEventSource)
        {
            /* Write to event log. */
            ReportEvent(hEventSource, EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE, 0, 0, NULL, 1, 0, (LPCTSTR*)&lpszStrings[0], NULL);
            DeregisterEventSource(hEventSource);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // As we are not running as a service, just write the error to the console.
        _putts(chMsg);
    }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Service startup and registration
inline void CServiceModule::Start()
{
    SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRY st[] =
    {
        { m_szServiceName, _ServiceMain },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };
    if (m_bService && !::StartServiceCtrlDispatcher(st))
    {
        m_bService = FALSE;
    }
    if (m_bService == FALSE)
        Run();
}


inline void CServiceModule::ServiceMain(DWORD /* dwArgc */, LPTSTR* /* lpszArgv */)
{
    // Register the control request handler
    m_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_START_PENDING;
    m_hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(m_szServiceName, _Handler);
    if (m_hServiceStatus == NULL)
    {
        LogEvent(_T("Handler not installed"));
        return;
    }
    SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING);

    m_status.dwWin32ExitCode = S_OK;
    m_status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    m_status.dwWaitHint = 0;

    // When the Run function returns, the service has stopped.
    Run();

    SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED);
    LogEvent(_T("Service stopped"));
}

inline void CServiceModule::Handler(DWORD dwOpcode)
{
    switch (dwOpcode)
    {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING);
        PostThreadMessage(dwThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
        break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE:
        break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE:
        break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
        break;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN:
        break;
    default:
        LogEvent(_T("Bad service request"));
    }
}

void WINAPI CServiceModule::_ServiceMain(DWORD dwArgc, LPTSTR* lpszArgv)
{
    _Module.ServiceMain(dwArgc, lpszArgv);
}
void WINAPI CServiceModule::_Handler(DWORD dwOpcode)
{
    _Module.Handler(dwOpcode);
}

void CServiceModule::SetServiceStatus(DWORD dwState)
{
    m_status.dwCurrentState = dwState;
    ::SetServiceStatus(m_hServiceStatus, &m_status);
}

void CServiceModule::Run()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    _Module.dwThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();

    //  If you are running on NT 4.0 or higher you can use the following call
    //  to make your service free threaded.
    //  This means that calls come in on a random RPC thread
    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    //  Otherwise, for single threaded use
    //  hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    //  In NT 4.0 and higher where DCOM is supported you may wish to initialize
    //  the security layer.  The following code will give you a DCOM service which
    //  would allow ALL users access to objects
    CSecurityDescriptor sd;
    sd.InitializeFromThreadToken();

    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_NONE, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IDENTIFY, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    //  If you wish to have your object creatable remotely using DCOM use the following
    hr = _Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE);
    //  Otherwise, only local activation
    //  hr = _Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE);
    ATLASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    while (true){}

    LogEvent(_T("Service started"));
    SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0))
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

    _Module.RevokeClassObjects();

    CoUninitialize();
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
extern "C" int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE /* hPrevInstance */,
    LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int /* nShowCmd */)
{
    _Module.Init(NULL, hInstance, IDS_SERVICENAME);
    _Module.m_bService = TRUE;

    TCHAR szTokens[] = _T("-/");
    TCHAR *szContext;
    LPTSTR lpszToken = _tcstok_s(lpCmdLine, szTokens, &szContext);
    while (lpszToken != NULL)
    {
        if (_tcsicmp(lpszToken, _T("UnregServer")) == 0)
            return _Module.UnregisterServer();

        if (_tcsicmp(lpszToken, _T("RegServer")) == 0)
            return _Module.RegisterServer(TRUE);

        if (_tcsicmp(lpszToken, _T("Embedding")) == 0)
            _Module.m_bService = FALSE;

        if (_tcsicmp(lpszToken, _T("LocalServer")) == 0)
        {
            _Module.SetupAsLocalServer();
            return 0;
        }
        lpszToken = _tcstok_s(NULL, szTokens, &szContext);
    }
    _Module.Start();

    // When we get here, the service has been stopped
    return _Module.m_status.dwWin32ExitCode;
}

void CServiceModule::SetupAsLocalServer()
{
    USES_CONVERSION;
    CRegKey keyClasses, key;
    LPOLESTR pCLSID;

    Uninstall();

    if (keyClasses.Open(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, _T("CLSID")) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return;

    _ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* pEntry = m_pObjMap;
    while (pEntry->pclsid != NULL)
    {
        StringFromCLSID(*pEntry->pclsid, &pCLSID);
        BSTR csTemp = pCLSID;
        if (key.Open(keyClasses, (LPCTSTR)csTemp) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            TCHAR szModule[_MAX_PATH];
            key.DeleteValue(_T("AppID"));
            key.DeleteValue(_T("_LocalServer32"));
            GetModuleFileName(GetModuleInstance(), szModule, _MAX_PATH);
            key.SetKeyValue(_T("LocalServer32"), szModule, _T(""));
        }
        pEntry++;
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
while (true){}
```

will loop forever, so your service will never set the SERVICE_RUNNING status.

Comment: Then How do I to run some instructions into a service?

Comment: while (true){} means halt on this line forever. Nothing after it will be run. You have a message loop just below this line, which will never be reached - that is where the service will look for instructions (I think).

Comment: How does it to detect which instructions to execute? And from where does it(compiler) begin executing (main methods)? I thought that I need to implement my instructions into that loop to make the service work, so, I've written that while loop in which I expect writting my business instructions.

Comment: Your service must call SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING) in a timely fashion when it is started. Currently you are not doing that as it can never reach that code. That is what is causing the error. You can have a loop where your service does stuff, but it must be after that call.

Comment: I've placed that loop just after the `SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_RUNNING);` instruction. But, the problem persists. Any suggestion, please?